# Корректное преобразование data.frame в строку заданными разделителям колонок и строк

Tags: r

Есть таблица.

```
> RTFMtable
 FF NN   TT   YY
 1 f1 22 aaaa  889
 2 f2 33   bb   99
 3 f3 44   cc   77
 4 f4 14   dd 1000
```

Мне нужно привести ее в строку с отдельными разделителями для колонок и строк. Должно получится так:

```
"f1@22@aaaa@889#f2@33@bb@99#f3@44@cc@77#f4@14@dd@1000"
```

Использую такой код:

```
rr<-apply( RTFMtable, 1,  paste, collapse = "@")
res<-paste(rr, collapse = "#" )
но получаю:
> res
[1] "f1@22@aaaa@ 889#f2@33@bb@  99#f3@44@cc@  77#f4@14@dd@1000"
```

Так как при применении paste в apply, если количество символов в "ячейках" таблицы разное, то apply как бы "добивает" пробелами.

```
 > rr
 [1] "f1@22@aaaa@ 889" "f2@33@bb@  99"   "f3@44@cc@  77"   "f4@14@dd@1000"
```

Просто так зачистить пробелы после преобразования я не могу, так как в реальных данных, могут содержаться пробелы.

Вопрос, как правильно схлопнуть таблицу в одну строку с заданными разделителями?

И я ,видимо, не понимаю как работает apply с таблицей, она же вроде работает с данными, а не с тем что выводится на экран, откуда берутся эти пробелы?

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока ждал ответа, нашел статю по теме: 
[Использование apply, sapply, lapply в R](https://habr.com/company/infopulse/blog/274611/)

Моя попытка использовать apply, была, конечно, некорректна - так как apply больше ориентирован на матрицы, и в случае разнородного типа данных в таблице проводит преобразования, которые могут оказаться с непредсказуемым результатом.

Корректное решение:

```
  RTFMres<-sapply( 1:nrow(RTFMtable), function (x, tbl) paste(tbl[x,], collapse = "@"  ), tbl=RTFMtable )
  RTFMres<-paste(RTFMres, collapse = "#" )
```

Здесь в качестве параметра на вход подается вектор номеров строк 1:nrow(RTFMtable), а в качестве применяемой к вектору функции указывается своя простейшая функция, которой в свою очередь передается как параметры, номер строки и сама таблица. По сути исполняется код типа:

```
 paste(RTFMtable[1,], collapse = "@"  )
 paste(RTFMtable[2,], collapse = "@"  )
 ...
 paste(RTFMtable[nrow(RTFMtable),], collapse = "@"  )
```

что дает нам вектор схлопнутых сток таблицы

```
> RTFMres
[1] "f1@22@aa@88" "f2@33@bb@99" "f3@44@cc@77"
```

который мы еще раз схлопываем с помощью paste

Вариант с использованием tidyr::unite (ответ выше) тоже хороший, и возможно быстрее, но мне было важно обойтись без использования дополнительных библиотек и разобраться в "глюке" apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
#so 846309
# готовим данные
FF  <- c("f1", "f2", "f3", "f4")
NN  <- c(22, 33, 44, 14)
TT  <- c("aaaa", " bb", "cc", "dd")
YY  <- c(889, 99, 77, 1000)

RTFMtable  <- data.frame(FF, NN, TT, YY)


> RTFMtable
  FF NN   TT   YY
1 f1 22 aaaa  889
2 f2 33   bb   99
3 f3 44   cc   77
4 f4 14   dd 1000

# подключаем пакет 
library (tidyr)
# объединяем столбцы в один
df  <- unite(RTFMtable, col = c("FF", "NN", "TT", "YY"), sep = "@")
# либо чтобы не перечислять все столбцы использовать: col = c(colnames(df))
> df
  c("FF", "NN", "TT", "YY")
1            f1@22@aaaa@889
2              f2@33@ bb@99
3               f3@44@cc@77
4             f4@14@dd@1000

# транспонируем 
s  <- t(df)

> s
                          [,1]             [,2]           [,3]          [,4]           
c("FF", "NN", "TT", "YY") "f1@22@aaaa@889" "f2@33@ bb@99" "f3@44@cc@77" "f4@14@dd@1000"

#результат
rslt  <- paste(s, collapse = "#")

> rslt
[1] "f1@22@aaaa@889#f2@33@ bb@99#f3@44@cc@77#f4@14@dd@1000"
```

Comment: Спасибо, а транспонирование обязательно - разве нельзя просто сделать paste(df, collapse = "#") ? Ведь df теперь из одной колонки.

Comment: Пробовал, `s  <- paste(df, collapse = "#")`, но результат меня не устроил:
`> s  [1] "c(\"f1@22@aaaa@889\", \"f2@33@ bb@99\", \"f3@44@cc@77\", \"f4@14@dd@1000\")"`. Выяснять причину не стал, использовал `t()`, да и логичнее код: получили одину колонку, а потом одну строку из множества колонок, которую и преобразовали.